# Java calculator class hierarchy issue

Tags: java

am basically attempting to create a calculator using a class hierarchy - the basic function will be:

Convert the String representation into a list of Tokens
Convert the List of Tokens into Polish Notation
Calculate the result on the basis of Polish Notation
I also need to represent objects -

numbers operators and brackets.

Following this i need to convert to polish notation - using a shunting yard algorithm and then compute the answer.

I am ok with understanding the shunting yard but am unsure as to the class hierarchy part.

The precedence is - Addition and Subtraction have a precedence of 2, and Multiplication and Division have a precedence of 3.

I am assuming i need a filereader class and also classes to handle the different objects.

I also need help in creating my own stacks and queues.

Thanks

Comment: It helps if you ask a question.  What is your specific issue?

Comment: No need for the word "basically."  It's a high-tech "um".  I see no class hierarchy here.

Answer (score 2):

No need for the word "basically."  It's a high-tech "um".

I see no class hierarchy here.  I'd recommend that you implement the functionality you need without a UI.  Just a stack, operands, and operators.  Get that working and then worry about UI.  There's little object-orientation needed.

Just separate the model from the view: Start with a text UI to get the functionality right, then add a GUI later.

Comment: I wouldn't even call it "high-tech". It's a "medium-tech um". 1+

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. It's just when i was asked to do this i was told i would need a hierarchy to represent the objects - numbers etc from the expressions that have been read in from the file.

Furthermore I have to implement my own stack and not use the java utils.

Comment: Who told you that you needed objects for numbers?  Don't listen to that person anymore.  Fine - a stack is easy to implement with a Java array as the private implementation of your own Stack class.  push(), pop(), peek(), isEmpty().  You shouldn't need more than those methods.  Your first and last thought should be: do the simplest thing that can possibly work, then build out.

Comment: it was my lecturer who gave me the advice on how to implement the data structures. so i take it all i have to do is create a stack class of my own and the use the shunting yard and RPN classes?

Comment: I don't know what a shunting yard is.  RPN *is* the stack: Push on the first operand, push on the second; pop off both when you encounter an operand and push the result back onto the stack.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. Here is a link to an explanation fo the shunting yard- 

http://andreinc.net/2010/10/05/converting-infix-to-rpn-shunting-yard-algorithm/

Comment: Thank you.  I think of it as an expression parse tree, with operator notes and operand leaves, evaluated using a breadth-first iterator.

Comment: So my new approach is to have the following classes-

List class
Node class
Shunting yard class
Main class

Main includes the reverse Polich notation, filereader and tokenizer. 

My question now is how would i link main to the shunting yard?

I was told I should create a list of objects which will be numbers, operands and brackets.

Thanks again